# LogicApp -> Event hub connector -> parse JSON -> triggerBody()?['Properteis'] is empty (after changing the pricing tier of Notification Hub?)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

After changing the pricing tier of Notification Hub (from Free to Basic), we noticed that one of our LogicApp (connected to Even Hub, where messages from IoTHub are forwarded) in the Parse JSON step has an empty content of `triggerBody()?['Properteis']`.

Any ideas what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: `Properteis` looks like a typo - should this rather be `Properties`?

Comment: Yes, it is Properties.
Everything worked fine for a long time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.